# Configure Token-Based Authentication in IIS

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I created a WebApi with Token-Based Authentication using this article [Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity) (many thanks to the author of this article) I was successful to create the application and it's working in my local machine.

**Problem:** When I deploy it in IIS as a subsite (its parent site is using Windows Authentication) it doesn't work. What am I missing. Please help.

**References:**

My WebApi Config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules></httpModules>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

And my parent Config

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when I finished my project, I deploy it as a separate application. I cannot deploy it as a subsite. Mixed authentication is a headache so, as much possible, work with your infra/security to sort out what authentication is needed in your application.